# How to remove the dot line block around the checkbox in simple_form & bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

On simple_form & bootstrap 3 integration page http://simple-form-bootstrap.plataformatec.com.br/, if checking the Active box, then there is a dot line block around the element (see image below):

[image]

We found the same dot line block in our Rails app. Is there a way to remove this dot line block?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think all browsers render that dotted line. Firefox does, but Chrome doesn't (from my quick tests).

Comment: IE does have dot line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this CSS

```
input, input:active, input:focus {
    outline: none;
}
/*and for firefox*/
input::-moz-focus-inner { 
    border: 0; 
}
```

Or set globally like

```
:focus {outline:none;}
::-moz-focus-inner {border:0;}
```

Although I would **highly** recommend creating your own style to keep the accessibility feature in place